# Should we delete hbmColor & hbmMask for a shared icon?

Tags: winapi, icons, gdi

I have a shared icon `HICON` from the following snippet.

```
::SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 500, &icon)
```

Then I retrieved its `ICONINFO` and copied out the `hbmColor` and `hbmMask`. As I notice in [other snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885412/3697757), people then call `::DeleteObject()` to destroy `hbmColor` and `hbmMask`.

Is that also valid for a shared icon?

As mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063(v=vs.85).aspx), we should not call `DestroyIcon` on a shared icon, which sounds like we should not call `DestroyObject` on a shared icon's `hbmColor` & `hbmMask` either.

> It is only necessary to call DestroyIcon for icons and cursors created
>   with the following functions: CreateIconFromResourceEx (if called
>   without the LR_SHARED flag), CreateIconIndirect, and CopyIcon.

Comment: It shares icons, it does not share ICONINFO structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `GetIconInfo` says:

> `GetIconInfo` creates bitmaps for the `hbmMask` and `hbmColor` members of `ICONINFO`. The calling application must manage these bitmaps and delete them when they are no longer necessary.

This is true equally for shared icons. You will have to delete the bitmaps when you are finished with them.